# If $X, Y$ have the included point topology, $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f$ preserves the included points

Tags: general-topology

For a prep exam:

My question is the following:

If $X, Y$ have the included point topology, $f: X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f$ preserves the included points.

Here is the definition of included point topology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology

I have tried:

$(\Rightarrow)$

By hypothesis we have that $f$ is continuous and $Y$ has the point included topology $\mathcal{H}$. From the definition of continuity we have that for every open set $V \in \mathcal{H}$ we have that $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T}$.

But in particular we have that for any open set $V$ we have that $p \in V$ or $V=\emptyset$, then
$$f^{-1}(p) \in f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T} \text{ or } f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$$

So we can conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ is the point included topology

$(\Leftarrow)$

By hypothesis we have that  $f$ preserves the included points, let's see that $f$ is a continuous function:

Be $A$ in $\mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ has the point included topology, let $A \in \mathcal{H}$ then
$$f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{T}$$

then $f$ is continuous

---

For been honest I am not sure about the concept of "preserves", Can someone please give me an indication in order to prove it.

Thank you very much

Comment: A set $X$ with the "included point" topology means there is a special point $p_X$ such that a nonempty subset $S\subset X$ is open in $X$ if and only if $p_X$ is a member of $S$. A mapping $f:X\to Y$, where both $X$ and $Y$ have the included point topology, is said to "preserve the included points" if $f(p_X) = p_Y$. In general, a mapping $f$ is said to "preserve" some property $\phi$ if $f(x)$ has property $\phi$ whenever $x$ does. In this case $\phi$ is the property of being the special point. Similarly, a function $f$ "preserves evenness" if $f(x)$ is even whenever $x$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand preservation we should have the following: Let $T$ be the topology in the point $p$ and $H$ in the point $q$.

Then we should have that $f(p)=q$.

($=>$). Let $V\in H=>f^{-1}(V)\in T=>p\in f^{-1}(V)=>f(p)\in V$. Thus it preserves $p$.

($<=$). Let $V\in H$. Then $q\in V=>f^{-1}(q)=p\in f^{-1}(V)$. Thus $f^{-1}(V)$ is open and $f$ is continuous.

In both situations if $V=\emptyset$ it as you wrote it above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not satisfied with the proofs shown above.

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_p)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_q)$ be two spaces with particular point topology. Let's show that **a function $f$ between them is continuous iff $f$ is constant or $f(p)=q$**.

The left implication is clear. Now, if $f$ is continuous then for every $A\subseteq X$, $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$, where the overline means closure. Then,
$$f(\overline{p})=f(X)\subseteq \overline{f(p)}.$$
Now, if $f(p)\neq q$, $\overline{f(p)}=f(p)$ so we have that the image of $X$ lies in $f(p)$, i. e., $f$ is constant.